# keras custom metric for path planning neural network doesnt work

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, metrics

Firstly some info about the background of the problem. I am building an artificial neural network solving an AGV path planning problem. The input of the network is a 15x15 grid terrain of 0,1 , meaning that 0 is empty space for the robot to go and 1 is an obstacle. There are 5 fixed destinations for all samples. The only thing changing is the terrain. My output is path between the start and destinations. I want to use a custom metric that measures how many obstacles are being hit and evaluate the produced path. Below is the code. I have already made an obs list in which, obs[0][sample_index]->obstacles of the train_sample[index] and obs[1][sample_index]->obstacles of the test_sample[index]. However the after the compile the model doesnt fit. Can someone explain to me what is the problem with the custom metric?

```
def index(y):
    if y in y_train:
        a=y_train.index(y)
    elif y in y_test:
        a=y_test.index(y)
    return a

def custom_metric(y_true, y_pred):

    ind=index(y_true)

    obs_in_ypred=0


    if y_true in y_train:
        for i in range(0,len(y_pred),2):
            if y_pred[i]*15+y_pred[i+1] in obs[0][ind]:
                obs_in_ypred=obs_in_ypred+1
    elif y_true in y_test:
        for i in range(0,len(y_pred),2):
            if y_pred[i]*15+y_pred[i+1] in obs[1][ind]:
                obs_in_ypred=obs_in_ypred+1
        
    metric1=1-obs_in_ypred/(len(obs[0][ind]))
    metric2=1-obs_in_ypred/(len(obs[1][ind]))

    return tf.keras.backend.in_train_phase(metric1,metric2)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't have `if` statement inside you loss function, the `if` has no gradient, just think about what's the derivative of `if`, i'm also fairly sure the `for` is no good either.

If the output is a path consider reproducing this path on a 2D tensor ( where maybe cells put to 1 give the path)

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I have thought about the path output as a 2D tensor of 0,1 indicating that the ones is the path, but since there are 5 destinations, the robot has to go through a cell multiple times and that cant be shown on the 2D tensor. Right?

Comment: now, understand that i have very little knowledge of the problem, so what im about to say may not make sense, but if a robot is going on a cell multiple times you could still use an integer to indicate how many times it passed ( if a robot passes on a cell 3 times you put 3 in that cell), anyway i think you should proceed in that direction (find a way to generate the output on a tensor) instead of generating a over-complex loss function

Comment: so instead of using a boolean 2D tensor you can use one made of integer, and then make regression on it (but understand that generating a 2D tensor as output needs a fully convoluted neural network)